# Debugging in R: At which position of list did the function fail?

Tags: r, list, function, debugging

I have four `lists` and a very long self-written `function`. `length(list)` is over 40.000.

An error occurs when running the function over the lists. I know how to repair the function, but I need to know at which position of the list `list[[x]]==?` the error occured, so I know which parameters went into the function.

Is there a call to find that out?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  We don't know what your function is doing and how the error occured.  So, without that, how do you expect others to comment.  If you want to continue running the function, may be use `tryCatch` with return value as NA or so.  Then, with `is.na`, you may be able to know the position where it didn't work

Comment: Presumably you are running `lapply`. in which case you can `lapply(seq_len(length(your_list)), function(list_idx) { print(list_idx); list_item = your_list[[list_idx]]; ... })`. This will print the index for each evaluation, and the most recent printed value is your culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `recover` in the options, i.e. run the following:

```
options(error = recover)
```

just before running your function over the list.

This will open the debugger just when the error occurs. Therefore, you can access the environment in that exact iteration (and get access to all objects / arguments) and see what went wrong.